# How to calculate conditional probability in r

Tags: r

[image]
[image]

This is the chart of consumers' willingness to pay. I have 2 times opportunity to drop the prices. I have to set the initial price and drop it two times, it's exhausting to calculate the conditional probability for every conditions. Can I use R to calculate it? For example, I set the initial price at $300, which is 15% possible that consumer willing to pay and then I set the price at $200, which conditional probability is ???, and the third one's probability is ???. I want to calculate the conditional probability in case of every possible initial price and second, third price. Thank you!

Comment: "I have 2 times opportunity to drop the prices. I have to set the initial price and drop it two times" can you explain yourself better? what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: what is exactly the repetitive task that you would like to automate? Start with how you are manually doing it (post 2 or 3 step pictures), and then show a final expected outcome. Also post the variables that will be used to derive the expected outcome.

Comment: At the beginning, I set a price at $300, the probability is 0.15, then I drop my price to $250, which conditional probability of selling my stuff is another figure, based on the initial price I set, finally I drop my price again, getting another probability of selling my stuff at this price.  What I what is the conditional probability in all scenarios (initial price, second price, third price)